# Geolocation on non https will still work on Ionic apps?

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, ionic2

getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins,
    and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching 
    your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. 
    See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

Geolocation API will be deprecated on non secure origin, but, what about local files on Ionic apps ? They said "localhost" is treated as secure origin, but it's not how cordova works.

Thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now they are only deprecating `http` urls, cordova use `file` urls, so right now it will still work.

I can't tell you if in the future google will decide to change that.

Anyway, if google some day does that, cordova will have to use a geolocation plugin instead of using the webview implementation, and that will fix the problem, so don't worry.